# How to return a generator from another function

Tags: python, generator-expression

I have a generator function which I want to call from another function and return the generator obtained. I can see two approaches here -

**Note that the below functions are simple dummy functions to illustrate the purpose. Please don't come up with better ways to implement those functions itself.**

Method 1

```
def fun_a(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i+10

def fun_b(n):
    if n < 0: 
        yield None
        return
    yield fun_a(n)
```

and use it as `list(list(fun_b(10))[0])` to get `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`

Method 2

```
def fun_b(n):
    if n < 0: 
        yield None
        return
    for i in fun_a(n):
        yield i
```

Then `list(fun_b(10))` can give me `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`.

While method 1 seems ok'ish, I don't want to return a list of list because in other cases I am returning a list and I don't want to mess up my code. Method 2 is just inefficient.

What would be a really good approach to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I you are using Python 3.3 or higher, you can use the [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) syntax introduced in PEP 380:

> PEP 380 adds the yield from expression, allowing a generator to delegate part of its operations to another generator. This allows a section of code containing yield to be factored out and placed in another generator. Additionally, the subgenerator is allowed to return with a value, and the value is made available to the delegating generator.

```
>>> def fun_a(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i+10

>>> def fun_b(n):
    if n < 0: 
        yield None
        return
    yield from fun_a(n)


>>> list(fun_b(10))
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>>
```

If not, then you'll just have to use the `for item in iterable:` syntax.

Comment: I knew about the `yield from` in Python 3. I am using python 2.7 but it is good to have a conclusive answer. I feel it is high time that I switch to python 3+ :)

Comment: @Unni Yup. I highly recommend you do. If only for the sane unicode support :P