# Modify a list by deleting the first element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. The output I receive from this code is not right.

Modify short_names by deleting the first element and changing the last element to Joe. Sample output from given program: `['Sam', 'Ann', 'Joe']`

```
short_names = ['Gertrude', 'Sam', 'Ann', 'Joseph']
"Your solution here"
print(short_names)
```

My code:

```
short_names = ['Gertrude', 'Sam', 'Ann', 'Joseph']

short_names.pop()
short_names.sort()

print(short_names)
```

Comment: `short_names.sort()` sorts the list, you should rather change the last element with `short_names[-1] = "Joe"`

Comment: are you familiar with indexing?

Comment: Also note `list.pop()` deletes from the _**back_** of the list, not the front. Python treats the end of the list as the top of the stack.

Answer (score 3):

You want to pop at index 0 (the first item). Without specifying the index, the default is the last index.

```
short_names.pop(0)
```

And to modify the last item, just modify the list at index -1.

```
short_names[-1] = "Joe"
```

Comment: This is the output Your output for the code['Sam', 'Ann', 'Joseph']
Expected output ['Sam', 'Ann', 'Joe']

Comment: @SHRIYADAHAL You need to modify the last element of the list: `short_names[-1] = "Joe"`.

Comment: @ChristianDean thanks, I missed that part of the question

Comment: @abccd Consider it even since you corrected me earlier about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047281/how-to-return-a-generator-from-another-function/45047300#45047300) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
  short_names = ['Gertrude', 'Sam', 'Ann', 'Joseph']  
  short_names[-1] = 'Joe'  
  short_names = short_names[1:len(short_names)]  
  print(short_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python del keyword is used to delete objects.Here, object can be variables, user-defined objects, lists, items within lists, dictionaries etc.

```
short_names = ['Gertrude', 'Sam', 'Ann', 'Joseph']
del short_names[0] #del will delete the object of short_names[0]
```

Copying short_names[1:] values from index 1 to last into a new reference variable short_names that means leaving 0 index value.

```
short_names=short_names[1:]
```

Lambda function copy values from 1 index to last index and return the list

```
short_=lambda x:x[1:]
print(short_(short_names))
```

Python list pop() is an inbuilt function in Python that removes and returns the last value from the List or the given index value.

```
 short_names.pop(0)#if index is not specified it will return last element
```

To update list
using negative index

```
short_names[-1]='jeo'
```

using positive indexing , find the length of string and reduce 1 from it because index are 0 based.

```
short_names[len(short_names)-1]='jeo'
```

delete the last element and then insert new element

```
short_names.pop()
short_names.append('jeo')
#or short_names.insert(index,value)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
user_input = input() 
short_names = user_input.split()

del short_names[0]       # delete the first element
short_names[2] = "Joe"   # change the last element to Joe

print(short_names)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me:

```
user_input = input()
short_names = user_input.split()

del short_names[0]
short_names[2] = 'Joe'


print(short_names)
```

Comment: This answer is a copy of the worst answer to this question... why?